# Reading 10 csv file and storing it in database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using JAVA 8 and Spring Boot.

I have 10 files(.csv) with a million row each.What's the best to read the files and store it in Database?

Comment: This Question is too broad. This site is for narrowly focused questions on a specific programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder and put all files inside this folder, and after this create a task in a cron for check if have files in the folder, if have you can develop a script in java or another language to load all the data the database

Comment: I am using JAVA

Comment: You can do it with java too, you can create a jar and execute by console.